# Use induction to show that $F_{2n} \equiv n(-1)^{n + 1} \pmod 5 \forall n \ge 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

> With $F_n$ being $n^{\textrm{th}}$ Fibonacci number, use induction to show that $F_{2n} \equiv n(-1)^{n + 1} \pmod 5$ for all $n \ge 1$.

I tried hard to prove this identity, but each time I'm failing to adjust the exponent of "$-1$". It would be nice if someone could come up with proof.

Thank you

Comment: I would use one of the many formulas for $F_{2n}$, (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html ) together with induction.

Comment: Just note that $F_n$ is periodic $\pmod 5$ with period $20$ so you only need to check a few cases.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's proven somewhere in Koshy's book on Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.

Comment: $F_{n+4}=3F_{n+2}-F_{n}$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Sometimes it is easier to prove something stronger. Prove simultaneously that

- $F_n \equiv 2n \bmod 5$ when $n \equiv 0 \bmod 4$
- $F_n \equiv 1n \bmod 5$ when $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$
- $F_n \equiv 3n \bmod 5$ when $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$
- $F_n \equiv 4n \bmod 5$ when $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$

Comment: The sequence $2,1,3,4$ is $2\cdot 3^n$ mod $5$ and is related to the fact that $3$ is a root of $x^2-x-1$ mod $5$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove that $F_n \equiv 2n \cdot 3^n \bmod 5$.

(This comes from Binet's formula mod $5$, because $3$ is a double root of $x^2-x-1$.)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1358341/589