# calculus sequence proof.

Tags: calculus

Is there any way to solve this besides proof by induction?

a sequence ${a_n}$ is defined by

$$a_1=3,a_{n+1}=3\sqrt{a_n} \quad\text{ for } n\geq 1$$

how do I show that $a_n<9$ and that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$. Why does this converge?

Comment: What's wrong with induction?

Comment: Nothing wrong with induction, I just wanted to know of any other way to approach this.

Comment: Given that the sequence is defined recursively, induction is the obvious way to prove it. One can elide it so that it seems like you aren't using it, but induction is the way to go here.

Comment: I know that induction is the way to go. As I said, I just wanted to know if there's any other way of doing it without induction.

Comment: Without induction you can't prove the sequence is well-defined, so the aim would have to be to prove without induction that any sequence $a_n$ satisfying $a_1=3,\,a_{n+1}=3\sqrt{a_n}$ satisfies $a_n<a_{n+1}<9$. I'm reminded of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1359020/56861) to another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Banach fixed-point theorem to prove that it converges, but it's an overkill: let
$$f(x)=3\sqrt{x}$$
Which means that it's derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
On $[3,16]$, we have that
$$\sup |f'| \leqslant \frac{3}{2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}<1$$
So $f$ will have exactly one fixed point, and for any $x_0 \in [3,16]$, $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ will converge to that fixed point.

Comment: is it also possible to perhaps use Monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @SamiShafi Yes, but that usually requires induction. Proving monotonicity and boundedness is not so hard with induction. You might be able to avoid induction with a lot of calculation or higher mathematical tools, but I don't really see a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$a_n=3^{2-2^{1-n}}$$ and clearly $$a_n<3$$

Comment: But how does one establish the formula formally? Induction.

Comment: Yes, for instance.

Comment: Which was what I mentioned: one can elide the induction so it *looks* like you are not using it, but that does not mean you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $a_n<9$ for all $n$ requires induction, as far as I'm concerned. However, once you know *that* (and also that $a_n>0$), the other inequality follows just from algebra:

$a_{n+1}-a_n = 3\sqrt{a_n}-a_n$, so let's consider $f(x)=3\sqrt x - x$. Then $f(x^2)= 3x-x^2 = x(3-x)> 0$ whenever $0<x<3$. In particular, $a_{n+1}-a_n = f(a_n) > 0$ whenever $0<\sqrt{a_n}<3$, i.e., whenever $0<a_n<9$.