# Prove $F_n=(-1)^{n+1}F_{-n}$ without induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the Fibonacci sequence defined by
$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n,~~~~~~F_1=F_2=1$$
I can prove via induction that $F_n=(-1)^{n+1}F_{-n}$, but how can it be proven without using induction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Binets formula: $$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n-(-\varphi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}\,?$$

Comment: @vitamind yes. Thanks for that, I really should have thought of that! You should probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binets formula
$$F_n = \frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}},$$
where $\phi$ denotes the golden ratio, is an explicit formula for the $n$-th Fibonacci number $F_n$. We have to prove that
$$\underbrace{\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}}_{F_n}=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\phi^{-n}-(-\phi)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}}_{F_{-n}}.$$
We can rewrite $(-1)^{n+1}\phi^{-n}$ to $-(-\phi)^{n}.$ Also $(-1)^{n+1}(-\phi)^{-n}$ is equal to $-\phi^n$. Putting all of this together yields
$$(-1)^{n+1}\cdot{\frac{\phi^{-n}-(-\phi)^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}} = \frac{-(-\phi)^{-n}-[-\phi^{n}]}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} = F_n$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead define $F_{-k}:=(-1)^{k+1}F_k$ for $k>0$, then verify the recursion relation still works viz.$$F_{-k}-F_{-k-1}-F_{-k-2}=(-1)^{k+1}(F_k+F_{k+1}-F_{k+2})=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I don't understand how this proof works; aren't you just showing that if $F_{-k}=(-1)^{k+1}F_k$ then the recursion still works? Who says there aren't other possible values for $F_{-k}$ such that the recursion also still works?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent It amounts to accepting the recursion relation uniquely determines the sequence. Without this, we can't talk of *the* Fibonacci sequence. It could be argued a *bit* of induction is needed to prove the sequence exists, but in $\mathsf{PA}^-$ we can prove *all* Fibonacci sequences have certain properties without induction. This is discussed in more detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1359020).

Comment: Sorry for being dense, would you mind explaining how it amounts to accepting the recursion relation uniquely determines the sequence?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent On the one hand, if it does the two definitions have to coincide; on the other hand, if it doesn't they don't. This is easier to work through by defining$$F^A_{-k}:=F^A_{-k+2}-F^A_{-k+1},\,F^B_{-k}:=(-1)^{k+1}F_k.$$

Comment: If it does, why do the two definitions have to coincide?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Because the above calculation shows $F^A,\,F^B$ both satisfy the recurrence relation.