# Axiom of Choice / Lemma 8.4.5 in Terence Tao Analysis I

Tags: analysis, self-learning, axiom-of-choice

**Lemma 8.4.5**: Let $E$ be a non-empty subset of the real line with $\sup (E)<\infty$ (i.e., $E$ is bounded from above). Then there exists a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ whose elements $a_n$ all lie in $E$, such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=\sup (E)$.

**Proof**: For each positive natural number $n$, let $X_n$ denote the set
\begin{align*}
X_n:=\{x \in E: \sup (E)-1 / n \leq x \leq \sup (E)\}
\end{align*}
Since $\sup (E)$ is the least upper bound for $E$, then $\sup (E)-1 / n$ cannot be an upper bound for $E$, and so $X_n$ is non-empty for each $n$. Using the axiom of choice (or the axiom of countable choice), we can then find a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_n \in$ $X_n$ for all $n \geq 1$. In particular $a_n \in E$ for all $n$, and $\sup (E)-1 / n \leq a_n \leq \sup (E)$ for all $n$. But then we have $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=\sup (E)$ by the squeeze test.

**My thought**: I understand that the Axiom of Choice is invoked because we intend to pick countably many elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ from countably many sets $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ such that $X_n=\{x \in E: \sup (E)-1 / n \leq x \leq \sup (E)\}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and there is no explicit rule how to pick these elements. However, I could also consider an alternative proof without invoking the notation of countably many sets:

We know that $\sup (E)$ is the least upper bound of $E$, and hence for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $x \in E$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sup (E)-\epsilon \leq x \leq \sup (E)
\end{align*}
We can construct a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:

1. Step 1: Let $\epsilon=1$. By the definition of $\sup (E)$, there exists $x_1 \in E$ such that $\sup (E)-1 \leq x_1 \leq \sup (E)$. Set $a_1=x_1$.
2. Step 2: Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. There exists $x_2 \in E$ such that $\sup (E)-\frac{1}{2} \leq x_2 \leq \sup (E)$. Set $a_2=x_2$.
3. Continuing in this manner, for each $n \geq 1$, let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$. There exists $x_n \in E$ such that $\sup (E)-\frac{1}{n} \leq x_n \leq \sup (E)$. Set $a_n=x_n$.

By this construction, we have $\sup (E)-\frac{1}{n} \leq a_n \leq \sup (E)$ for all $n \geq 1$. Therefore, $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=\sup (E)$ by the squeeze theorem.

**My question**: Does the alternative proof still rely on the Axiom of Choice? That is, as we explicitly state the existence of each element $x_n$ and define $a_n = x_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it seems to me that no Axiom of Choice is needed. If I am wrong and the Axiom of Choice is still invoked, does it mean that the Axiom of Choice is always needed when constructing a sequence with infinitely many terms?

Comment: The second proof still uses choice because "for all $n$ the set of values I could pick for $a_n$ (subject to $\sup(E)-2^{1-n}\le a_n\sup(E)$) is nonempty" only implies "there is a sequence that manages to do it" with choice. See "The Cartesian product of any family of nonempty sets is nonempty" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents).

Comment: @J.G. Thanks. This is very helpful. However, would it imply that without the Axiom of Choice, the concept of a sequence is itself empty, since such a function may not exist? See e.g.:
Definition 5.1.1 (Sequences). Let $m$ be an integer. A sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n=m}^{\infty}$ of rational numbers is any function from the set $\{n \in \mathbf{Z}: n \geq m\}$ to $\mathbf{Q}$, i.e., a mapping which assigns to each integer $n$ greater than or equal to $m$, a rational number $a_n$. 
Or where is my mistake?

Comment: By the way your explicit formula *setting $a_n$ to be the middle point* does not work because there is no guarantee that $a_n \in E$.

Comment: If sequences are specific functions, they're well-defined, but their existence may be contingent on specific assumptions, even if only something "obvious" like that Cartesian product version of choice. To take [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1359020), if you drop induction you can't say "the" Fibonacci series, only prove certain things are true of "all" $F_0=0,\,F_1=1,\,F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$ sequences, without even being able to prove there is one.

Comment: @LeeMosher Okay, thanks, I see the point. If $E$ contains only rational numbers and $\sup (E)=\sqrt{n}$, then $a_n=\frac{\sup (E)-\frac{1}{n}+\sup (E)}{2}=\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{2n}$ is not in $E$. So an explicit choice function does not exist. Might this be the reason that the Axiom of Choice is necessarily invoked?

Comment: One way to see why this argument is problematic on a moral level is that your sets $X_n$ may be extremely pathological. Thus, saying whether any given real number is or is not in $X_n$ may be very difficult. You have existence of $x_n \in X_n$, but do you have any procedure which can actually calculate that $x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence needs to be defined by a finite formula. So to define the sequence $(a_n)$, you need to write down a statement which specifies the values of the $a_n$'s *simultaneously, all at once*.

For example, you have given an explicit formula that simultaneously defines each of the nonempty sets $X_n$, one for each $n$. That works just fine. Therefore, you have a *sequence of sets $X_n$*. The definition of that sequence did not require the axiom of choice.

Your "alternate definition" for the sequence $(a_n)$ uses infinitely many formulas: for each natural number $n$, you have a formula which applies [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) to choose an element from the nonempty set $X_n$. So you have infinitely many statements, each with a separate application of existential instantiation. But that doesn't count: you are not allowed to define a sequence by infinitely many applications of existential instantiation, nor by any conjunction of infinitely many separate defining statements.

To define the sequence $(a_n)$, you need choose one $a_n$ from each of the nonempty sets $X_n$ *simultaneously*. That's exactly what the axiom of countable choice lets you do. Think of it as *simultaneous existential instantiation*.